# Chrome.browserAction.enable() / Chrome.browserAction.disable() fails between tab switches (possible bug in chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that reads a tab's title onActivated and onUpdated 
and then calls either disable or enable (as below) based on the tab title

```
enable = function(text,tabId){
    if (tabId){
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[255,0,0,255]});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:text,tabId:tabId});
        chrome.browserAction.enable(tabId);
    }
}
disable = function(text,tabId){
    if (tabId){
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:text,tabId:tabId});
        chrome.browserAction.disable(tabId);
    }
}
```

so some web pages will have the extension popup enabled and some will not:

when you go from a page that is "disabled" to "enabled" the icon lights up and the extension appears active but when you try and left click the extension does not work, and the popup fails to open

however if you right click first and then left click it opens

How do I get it so that when the extension icon is enabled (after being disabled) that it also allows the user to left click it to open the popup without having to right click first

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please make a minimal but complete example.

Comment: Resides, have you considered making a `pageAction` instead? From the docs: _"Don't use browser actions for features that make sense for only a few pages. Use page actions instead."_

Comment: I'll see if I can get a example working tomorrow,
I have taken a video of the problem: https://www.screenr.com/834N
It's not obvious initially when I am right or left clicking but I make it clearer later in the video

Comment: Note how in your video it stops highlighting the button on hover (which it absolutely should always do). You are hitting a bug in Chrome (congrats!). So, now your work is to make a minimal example, and submit it as a bug to https://crbug.com/ - we cannot help you here. Your code seems to be correct from what you presented.

Comment: I have submitted the bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421778&thanks=421778&ts=1412843654 and attached a .zip file to the post which contains a minimal extension which recreates the bug

Comment: For completeness it is located here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxuZdgzIoYJCZmFRb1lRMzdMNzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @arcanine I posted a follow-up to your ticket on the issue tracker. Could you respond to it? And also visit https://code.google.com/hosting/settings to enable email notifications so that requests for clarifications don't get lost.